# Funny name/ Incomplete Attachment / wrong extension - Mail Python

Tags: python, email

I am sending mail from a linux box from a directory path which has three csv files. I want to attach all three in my email. Below is the script.

```
def mailer(sender, to, path):

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'UMR_EOD_RECONCILLATIONS'
    msg['From']    = sender
    msg['To']      = to

    for file in os.listdir(path):
        f = open( path + file, 'rb')
        csv = MIMEText(f.read())
        f.close()
        msg.attach(csv)

    mailer = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    mailer.sendmail(sender,to, msg.as_string())
    mailer.quit()
```

I have been scratching my head for a while and tried multiple times but still facing below issues.

- The files which are attached are text files i.e. .txt extension, I want is to be csv
- The files have funny names `ATT00001.txt` and `ATT00002.txt` which remains the same.
- The third file is never attached to the mail it contents are outputted  in the body and it's the damn same file however times I may try.

I have tried setting below but to no avail.

```
msg["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + file + ";"

msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)
```

Comment: As a debugging technique, try sending yourself the files using your email client (Outlook, Thunderbird, GMail, whatever). Then, when you recieve the email, look for a "view source" menu item to examine the email. See how your email client formatted the mail differently than how your Python program did.

Comment: In outlook I don't see option for view source.

Comment: What if you do `csv.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)` before `msg.attach(csv)` and add a body text before via `email_body = MIMEText("Hi me, here are your CSVs!", "plain")` and then `msg.attach(email_body)` ?

Comment: thx, I was picking this line directly from pydocs `msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)`
        however there msg is not my msg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The first text object will be displayed as the email message. So, add an extra text object first.

2) CSV files should be transmitted as `content-type: text/csv`, not `content-type: text/plain`.

```
#UNTESTED
def mailer(sender, to, path):

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'UMR_EOD_RECONCILLATIONS'
    msg['From']    = sender
    msg['To']      = to

    msg.attach(MIMEText('Here are the reports you asked for.'))

    for file in os.listdir(path):
        f = open( path + file, 'rb')
        csv = MIMEText(f.read(), 'csv')
        f.close()
        csv.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)

        msg.attach(csv)

    mailer = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    mailer.sendmail(sender,to, msg.as_string())
    mailer.quit()
```

Comment: thanks so much, it solved all three problems. I was using Content-Disposition after `msg.attach(csv) therefore it was not working. And no output in body now. :)

Answer (score 4):

I always advise to run from doing MIME stuff when you just want to send emails. I feel like no one wants to deal with that. It feels like Java.

Try [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail); my apologies, I'm the developer.

Its purpose is to make it super easy to send emails with HTML, inline images and attachments.

The code for what you want:

```
import os
import yagmail

def mailer(sender, to, path):
    yag = yagmail.SMTP(sender, host="localhost", smtp_skip_login=True)
    contents = ['Here are the reports you asked for.'] + os.listdir(path)
    yag.send(to, 'UMR_EOD_RECONCILLATIONS', contents)
```

I'd suggest to read the [README](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) for more nice tricks in there :)

To get started, use `pip install yagmail` to install yagmail.